# How to connect to redis which is running on EC2, from node.js application running on local system using Express.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, redis, ubuntu-server

I am writing an Node.js application on Express.js. I have a Redis server installed on an EC2 instance running on UBUNTU Server 16.04. I have installed npm modules for Redis.I have mentioned the port and the host like this:-

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(6379,"127.0.0.1");
```

When I try connecting to EC2 instance of Redis, I get an error like this:-

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1061:14)
```

How do I connect to redis which is running on ec2?

Comment: Have you tried tunneling over ssh?

Comment: I use Putty. It is equivalent to normal ssh I suppose

Comment: You will need the proper IP address of your Redis server on EC2 and that IP address needs to be reachable from your local system where you're trying to connect to it from.

Comment: And could you please tell me where and how I can specify that address?

Comment: You really shouldn't expose Redis to the internet. Assuming this is for development work only and the code will eventually live on the same server, then an ssh tunnel is simple enough and is secure.

Comment: @jfriend00 Could you please tell me how I can posiibly connect to Redis running on a seperate instance, from my node.js application running on my local system?

Comment: @CoderPJ did you get a solution to connect Redis from nodeJS app or you started using AWS Elasticache which fully manages Redis?

Answer (score 0):

from the error message, it seems like redis isn't actually running on your host. i would check that redis is indeed running like this:

```
ps auxwg | grep redis
```

and check for a running redis process. another, simpler way would be to use the 'telnet' command to attempt to connect your local redis instance like:

```
wintermute:~ 07:52:58 melgart$ telnet 127.0.0.1 6379
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

in my case, redis *is* up and running so i get the 'connected' response. HTH